# How to make a simple embeddable scripting language for C++?

Tags: c++, scripting, game-engine

I'm building a game engine and can't quite find a scripting language that does what I want, and is embeddable into C++. Therefor, the natural solution is to build my own.

I know the basics about Flex, Bison, peg/leg, and a little about VMs. Can I use this knowledge to build a small scripting language for a game engine? How would I implement an embedded language? I'm not really sure where to start off building such a small language.

Comment: One of the signs things are going really bad in design is when you think you need to build a new language. Lua and Angelscript are popular scripting for games. Hope that helps.

Comment: [boost::python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) or QtScript are script languages embeddable in C++

Comment: *can't quite find a scripting language that does what I want* What languages have you considered? What don't they offer?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I've tried boost::python, Lua, and taken a look at Google V8. None of them really meet both of my requirements, which are: **1.** Have a implementation of classes. **2.** Be easy to embed. *UnrealScript* (the scripting language of the *Unreal Engine*) is one of my favorite examples of a perfect scripting language, but it isn't open source as far as I know.

Comment: JS and Lua can both fake classes pretty well, if you ignore the most powerful parts of either language.  But to the point of the question:  If you have to ask how to make a scripting language, you're not yet ready to make one that will actually be used by an audience of anyone but you.

Comment: [AngelScript](http://www.angelcode.com) is uber flexible and integrates extremely well in both directions with C++ projects.

Answer (score 3):

A common scripting language for use with C++ is [Lua](http://www.lua.org/). You can implement it with [Luabind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind.html) or another binding, there are plenty (and there are even tutorials to write your own).

Another option is to use Python with [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/index.html).